# Update variables - Titanium/Javascript

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

i am working on a titanium mobile project and i'd like to update some variables.

How can i update some variables that is in the "exports.presets"? It looked easy to me but unfortunately i couldnt do this..

```
exports.presets = {

    Filter1:new superimageview.Filter(function(){
        this.brightness(slider1.value)
            .saturation(slider2.value)
            .contrast(slider3.value)
            .channels({r:0.4,g:0.6,b:0.2});
    }),
    Filter2:new superimageview.Filter(function(){
        this.brightness(slider1.value)
            .saturation(slider2.value)
            .contrast(slider3.value)
            .channels({r:0.2,g:0.1,b:0.1});
    }),
    Filter3:new superimageview.Filter(function(){
        this.brightness(slider1.value)
            .saturation(slider2.value)
            .contrast(slider3.value)
            .channels({r:0.0,g:0.2,b:0.6});
    })
};
//



var slider1 = Titanium.UI.createSlider({
    top: 20,
    min: -0.5,
    max: 0.5,
    width: '100%',
    value: 0
    });
slider1.addEventListener('change', function(e) {

  label.text = e.value;
   // XXX What to do here?
});
```

Comment: I see no array here. *Did you mean `exports.presets`?*. That's not an array.

Comment: ohh sorry, exports.presets i meant.

Comment: You might want to check out the structure of `exports.presets` by outputting into a console or something.

Comment: OK, but how it helps to me?

Comment: Your example is unclear, I don't know what `superimageview.Filter` is reffereing to code wise.

Comment: @Tel4tel outputting to a console will tell you the structure of your object so you will know how to access and modify values.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming you are in the same module like in your code, otherwise drop the "exports":

```
slider1.addEventListener('change', function(e) {

  label.text = e.value;
   // XXX What to do here?
   // This! Update the presets with new values.
   // Im guessing slider1 coincides with Filter1
   exports.presets.Filter1 = new superimageview.Filter(function(){
        this.brightness(slider1.value)
            .saturation(slider2.value)
            .contrast(slider3.value)
            .channels({r:0.4,g:0.6,b:0.2});
   });

});
```

That will set the preset values to the updated values of your slider.

Comment: Sorry, it is not passing the slider values..Ive sent you an email tho.. @JosiahHester